# How to set PartitionKey when using spring cloud stream Kinesis

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream

In my code, I used `setHeader`.

```
mysource.getChannel1()
        .send(MessageBuilder
        .withPayload(new Person("messageA", 1))
        .setHeader("partitionKey", 345).build());
```

In the properties file I have added:

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.channel1.producer.partitionKeyExpression = 
                                                      headers['partitionKey']
```

But still, the PartitionKey is not `345` the `partitionKey` is some hash value `2133325211`. 
Even I insert 2 messages with the same `partitionKey`'s header, in `Kinesis` we get 2 different partition keys.

When I try

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.producer.partitionKeyExpression = payload.id
```

The `partitionKey` is always equal to `partitionKey-0`

**My question:**

How do I set the partition key to a specific value?

Comment: Why don't you accept the correct answer

Answer (score 3):

The problem that the current implementation relies on the built-in algorithm in the SCSt for the `BinderHeaders.PARTITION_HEADER`, which produce a `partition number`, which doesn't fit to the Kinesis nature how we should select the particular shard. Well, actually we don't select it at all. We provide some partition key value to let message to settle in the same shard by the hash from that value. Or we can provide an explicit hash to be sure that we go to the same shard. Essentially it is the same in the end - we end up with the shard by the hash.

To make it working for your `payload.id` use-case I suggest to take a look into the `BinderHeaders.PARTITION_OVERRIDE` header approach:

```
@Bean
@GlobalChannelInterceptor(order = Integer.MIN_VALUE, patterns = Source.OUTPUT)
public ChannelInterceptor partitionOverrideInterceptor(BindingProperties bindingProperties,
        StandardEvaluationContext evaluationContext) {

    return new ChannelInterceptorAdapter() {

        @Override
        public Message<?> preSend(Message<?> message, MessageChannel channel) {
            return MessageBuilder.fromMessage(message)
                    .setHeader(BinderHeaders.PARTITION_HEADER,
                            bindingProperties.getProducer()
                                    .getPartitionKeyExpression()
                                    .getValue(evaluationContext, message))
                    .build();
        }

    };
}
```

This way the `scst_partition` header will have exact value you would like to provide via your `partitionKeyExpression` and `KinesisMessageHandler` will have a proper value for target hashing in the `PutRecordRequest`.

See https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-aws-kinesis/issues/52 for more info.

Comment: I am getting error with BindingProperties bean doesn't exist in the context? Should it be autoconfigured with spring boot/cloud from application properties/ym or additional configuration is needed?

Comment: Please, consider to raise a new SO question with much more info.